# Cannot set up Drone : NoClassDefFoundError: com/opera/core/systems/OperaDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I'm following this tutorial: http://arquillian.org/guides/functional_testing_using_graphene/

But I got this error:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.047 sec <<< FAILURE!
cn.ftc.test.BeanTest  Time elapsed: 1.045 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opera/core/systems/OperaDriver
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1793)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.Reflections.getObserverMethods(Reflections.java:52)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ExtensionImpl.of(ExtensionImpl.java:51)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.inject(ManagerImpl.java:198)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:58)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.ServiceRegistryLoader.createServiceInstance(ServiceRegistryLoader.java:108)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.ServiceRegistryLoader.all(ServiceRegistryLoader.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneRegistrar.registerConfigurators(DroneRegistrar.java:74)
at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneRegistrar.register(DroneRegistrar.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:97)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 41 more


Results :

Tests in error: 
  cn.ftc.test.BeanTest: com/opera/core/systems/OperaDriver

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Here is my `arquillian.xml`:

```
<extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">firefox</property>
</extension>

<container qualifier="JBOSS_AS_MANAGED_7.X" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <!-- <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m ${jacoco.agent}</property> -->
        <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        <property name="jbossHome">/home/neo/app/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

And here is my `dependency`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Arquillian Core dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Arquillian Drone dependencies and WebDriver/Selenium dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- webdriver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene2}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

I was running this test in a remote JBoss-as-7.1.1 Server. I do not understand why the `operadriver` is needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency `org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain:pom` is not needed.

It should be enough to use dependencies listed in the tutorial.

You can upgrade version though, to:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies specify in the POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

have dependency on groupId **com.opera** and artifact **operadriver**

Plz see the maven link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.extension/arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain/1.2.0.Final

Comment: I added this dependency, But I still got the same error.

Comment: u facing issue while compiling the code or running ? If compiling then check at .m2 repo and if running it check the lib exist in the classpath

Comment: Weird. JBoss repository does not have this dependency. `Failure to find org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain:jar:1.2.0.Final in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of JBoss repository has elapsed or updates are forced`

Comment: You can go with maven repository.

Comment: I have figured this out. I do have operadriver.jar in my repository, but it was broken. I fixed it by deleting this file and rebuild the project. Thanks for your help!

Comment: so mean ur issue is fixed .. Gud enjoy the running code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the fact that Opera Driver is missing from classpath. Including the whole Drone web driver depchain will solve the issue. Note that the packaging type of `arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain` artifact is `pom` so make sure that when including the dependency to your project, you define `type` as `pom`. This way all of its dependencies will be added as transitive dependencies to your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
    <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have figured this out. I do have operadriver.jar in my repository, but it was broken. I fixed it by deleting this file and rebuild the project.